# Way to go to parse some "funky" JSON data with .Net and C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, deserialization, datacontract

The webservices I am connecting to send as response to our queries some JSON data organised in a weird way (no doubt they have done it wrong, but we cannot change it).

I am quite new to C# and have managed to deserialize some more standard JSON objects using DataContract and DataContractJsonSerializer.

However, I am rather puzzled with those twisted JSON we are getting. On our java client (Android), we have simply decided to go with a simple JSON parser that skips the extra arrays they have inserted. I would love to get some opinion from experienced developers on how to get  this twisted JSON deserialized.

Here is what a web service to get some user details would send and the C# object it is supposed to correspond to :

**C#**

```
class Buddy 
{
  public String Login { get; set; }
  public String Password { get; set; }
  public List<Purchase> { get; set; }
}

class Purchase
{
  public Int64 ItemId { get; set; }
  public Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "buddy": 
      [
        {
          "login": "johndoe",
          "password": "pwd",
          "purchase_list": 
            [
              {
                "purchase": 
                  [
                    {
                      "item_id": 1654,
                      "qty": 1
                    }
                  ]
              },
              {
                "purchase": 
                  [
                    {
                      "item_id": 654,
                      "qty": 2
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Seems you could just strip out all the `[` and `]` and be left with 'normal' JSON?

Comment: Except the 'purchase' object has invalid syntax....

Comment: Your C# is also invalid, please fix these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The library introduced here is quite effective for handling json :
http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx